# Algorithm for transforming JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, algorithm

I have been struggling with this one a lot:

I am trying to add some colors to a map (JQuery Vector Maps) The sintax to add color to a country is the following (Jquery)

```
$('#map').vectorMap('set', 'colors', { br: '#CCDDAA' });
$('#map').vectorMap('set', 'colors', { us: '#CCDDAA' });
```

As you can see you could go with that approach or the following:

```
var gdpData = {"br":"#CCDDAA", "us":"#CCDDAA"};
$('#map').vectorMap('set', 'colors', gdpData);
```

The thing is that my controller returs JSON Information like this:

```
[{"Id":2,"Country":"US","CountryCode":"us"},{"Id":4,"Country":"BR","CountryCode":"br"}]
```

I have the lower case CountryCode which is fine, and the color I want to set it on the JS side depending on some values.

This is what I have done: I think I have 2 paths,

First manipulate the JSON to make it look like `{"br":"#CCDDAA", "us":"#CCDDAA"};` but I don't know how to do it :(

Or call the set colors line by line however this approach requires the country code without quotes.

```
 $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: '/Statistics/GetCoutriesListed/',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data)
            {
                $.each([data], function (index, value)
                {
                    //This is not working of course due to quotes.
                    $('#map').vectorMap('set', 'colors', value[0].CountryCode: '#CCDDAA');
                 //And I don't know how to do this :(
                $('#map').vectorMap('set', 'colors', { JASON IN CORRECT FORMAT });

                });
            }
        });
```

What could be a good approach for handling this? Do you have any ideas or recommendations? I am not strong at all in JS, Jquery.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the colour always going to be `#CCDDAA`?

Comment: Just an observation on your code: `data` is already and array so you don't need to use `[]` when passing it into `each`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this;

```
$.each([data], function (index, value) {
    var f = value[index].CountryCode,
        obj = {};
    obj[f] = "#CCDDAA";
    $('#map').vectorMap('set', 'colors', obj);
});
```

Comment: You sir rock! This fixed the issue. Thanks! Simple and elegant.

Comment: Np :) Glad to help! @MRFerocius

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the array of objects:

```
var transformedData = arr.map(function (el) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[el.Country.toLowerCase()] = '#CCDDAA';
  return obj;
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3BweA/12/).

Comment: Andy! Excellent! Thanks this works excellent too! I selected display_name since answered first and worked. I am trying your approach too!